# What is the temperature of a single proton?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, protons

As it is said in general classical statistical mechanics, that temperature is nothing but just an integrating factor and **T**($E_{avg}$). And as proton is not a fundamental particle rather have inner structure is it okay to ask for temperature of a single proton (in deep space, with no electromagnetic interaction, gravity nothing)?

Comment: It depends how fast it is moving, i.e. on your observational frame of reference.

Comment: No that quest is different, it will follow Maxwell boltzmann distribution.. so single molecule can possibly have energy but temp?....

Answer (score 2):

The proton is a bag of bound by color forces valence quarks and a sea of quark antiquarks and gluons, in the usual representation:

[image: proton]

It is reasonable to ask whether a temperature can be defined, and yes, in the [lattice QCD solutions](https://quark.phy.bnl.gov/~pisarski/talks/Colloquia/Fodor.pdf) there is a variable called temperature. Here is another [paper.](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0608013).

The q[uark gluon plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark%E2%80%93gluon_plasma#Thermodynamics) does have a temperature, and so in the cosmological models the formation of nucleons will have a transition temperature, from plasma to bound quarks.

There exists a  [QCD matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QCD_matter) article in the wikipedia, which is relevant:

[image: qcdphase]

> Conjectured form of the phase diagram of QCD matter, with temperature as ordinate (in mega-electron volts) and quark chemical potential as abscissa.

It is still a matter of research.

Answer (score 0):

We can define temperature as $T$ the parameter of the [Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution):

$$ p_i = \frac{1}{Z} e^{-E_i/kT} $$

With $p_i$ being the probability to have the system in a state with energy $E_i$.
And $Z$ being the normalization constant.

Now, under "a proton" we usually mean a system of three $uud$ valent quarks plus the surrounding excitation of the quark-gluon fields -- all in the ground (lowest energy) state.  Since our definition restricts us to ground state only, we have $p_0 = 1$ and $p_i=0$ for $i>0$.  Which for the Boltzmann distribution means $T=0$.

So, the formal answer to your question is $T=0$.

If you are interested whether it is possible to have the system of three $uud$ valent quarks plus the surrounding excitation of the quark-gluon fields in some non-groun state -- check [the Delta barion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_baryon).

Answer (score -3):

There is no heat radiation bound in the force field of proton; the quarks inside proton possess some different radiations